# What is Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 used for?

Tags: document, explorer

What is Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 used for?

Comment: Real question or not, I had the same ... 'question.'

Comment: I had the same question too. Seems real to me.

Comment: NOTE - This also comes as part of the Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 installation. I had to find this out the hard way...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's the help viewer used with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: can you drop some link from msdn??

Answer (score 14):

it helps you to view msdn library, visual studio documentation, .net framework sdk documentation in your computer while working offline.

Comment: can you drop some link from msdn??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29e691fz(VS.90).aspx